# How to read blocks from a floppy with sectors?

Tags: c, block, head, sector, floppy

I need to read a floppy from a pre OS state and I have a function to read, but it cannot seem to read past the 4th sector...

```
void get_block(blk, buf) int blk; char buf[]
{
   int cyl, head, sector;

   cyl = ((blk*2) / 18) / 2;
   head = ((blk*2) / 18) % 2;
   sector = (blk*2) % 18;

   // Read first sector <<Dies here if blk > 2>>
   diskr(cyl, head, sector, buf);

   // Increment
   if ((sector = (++sector % 18)) == 0)
      if ((head = (++head % 2)) == 0)
         cyl++;

   // Read second sector <<Dies here if blk == 2>>
   diskr(cyl, head, sector, buf+512);
}
```

Any idea why? Am I converting from blocks incorrectly?

Comment: Woah! Pre-ANSI C!  It's been a while since I've seen that...

Comment: See if the first code sample in this question helps.  He also references what you may want to do a google search on: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/59310-reading-floppy-disk-sector.html

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Seems appropriate considering the task at hand :D

Answer (score 2):

No, assuming your disk is a 1.44M "floppy" (80 cylinders, 2 heads/cylinder, 18 sectors/head, 512 bytes/sector), those calculations should be okay, as shown with the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    int blk, cyl, head, sector;
    for (blk = 0; blk <= 18; blk++) {
        cyl = ((blk*2) / 18) / 2;
        head = ((blk*2) / 18) % 2;
        sector = (blk*2) % 18;
        printf ("%2d (a) -> %2d %2d %2d", blk, cyl, head, sector);
        if ((sector = (++sector % 18)) == 0)
            if ((head = (++head % 2)) == 0)
                cyl++;
        printf (" (b) -> %2d %2d %2d\n", cyl, head, sector);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the output of which is:

```
 0 (a) ->  0  0  0 (b) ->  0  0  1
 1 (a) ->  0  0  2 (b) ->  0  0  3
 2 (a) ->  0  0  4 (b) ->  0  0  5
 3 (a) ->  0  0  6 (b) ->  0  0  7
 4 (a) ->  0  0  8 (b) ->  0  0  9
 5 (a) ->  0  0 10 (b) ->  0  0 11
 6 (a) ->  0  0 12 (b) ->  0  0 13
 7 (a) ->  0  0 14 (b) ->  0  0 15
 8 (a) ->  0  0 16 (b) ->  0  0 17
 9 (a) ->  0  1  0 (b) ->  0  1  1
10 (a) ->  0  1  2 (b) ->  0  1  3
11 (a) ->  0  1  4 (b) ->  0  1  5
12 (a) ->  0  1  6 (b) ->  0  1  7
13 (a) ->  0  1  8 (b) ->  0  1  9
14 (a) ->  0  1 10 (b) ->  0  1 11
15 (a) ->  0  1 12 (b) ->  0  1 13
16 (a) ->  0  1 14 (b) ->  0  1 15
17 (a) ->  0  1 16 (b) ->  0  1 17
18 (a) ->  1  0  0 (b) ->  1  0  1
```

I'm a *little* concerned about the undefined behavior nature of:

```
if ((sector = (++sector % 18)) == 0)
```

construct, preferring something like:

```
if ((sector = (sector + 1) % 18)) == 0)
```

but, if it gives you the right values, it should be okay. However, you need to check that it *does* give you the right values *in the environment where you're running.* That fact that it does in my version of `gcc` doesn't mean it will in your case.

Or you could just use the suggested form above which *is* defined.

The failure point that you have is nowhere near the switch-over between heads or cylinders, so I don't think it's a wrapping issue, but you should print out the values in your environment if possible.

When you say you "can't read past the 4th sector", you should specify *exactly* what that means? Does the machine freeze, do you get a disk error, does it return what you think is rubbish?

There is the possibility that the disk is not formatted correctly, or that it's faulty, there's also the possibility that it just doesn't have the data there that you expect to see. It may be worthwhile formatting a floppy with DOS/Windows/whatever and checking what that does in your program.

Comment: "I'm a little concerned about the: if ((sector = (++sector % 18)) == 0) construct" -- You should be a lot concerned about it.  Even though it gives him and you right values today, it won't tomorrow.  Or who knows, maybe it didn't give him right values today and maybe that's his problem.

Comment: Hence my comment to check them. I can't be bother looking up to see whether that's undefined due to the lack of a sequence point, since it's easily fixed (whether needed or not) by the more readable version (IMNSHO). But I'm not overly concerned about it not working tomorrow (on a later compiler) given that it's using K&R-style non-prototype functions :-)

Comment: OK, I thought it was instantaneously obvious that there were two assignments to sector without a sequence point in between.  K&R didn't say which assignment would "win".

Comment: @paxdiablo By can't read past the 4th sector I mean, when I read in the group descriptor (block 2, Cyl 0, head 0, sec 4-5) get_block will read in the 4th block then freeze at diskr(). And _windows I have print statements that show I'm getting the right values